# Not respected assumptions

Tags: functions, function-construction, parametric-functions

I' m writing a function with the following line:

```
f[α_,x_, y_] := f[α,x,y] = 
Assuming[α > 0,Normalize[ E^(-α √(x^2 + y^2)),
Integrate[#,{x,-∞,∞},{y,-∞,∞}]&]];
```

The output I have is

```
ConditionalExpression[(E^(-Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] α) α^2)/(
 2 π), Re[α] > 0]
```

I don' t understand why it does ignore a constraint I gave in the assumptions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Integrate[
 E^(-\[Alpha] \[Sqrt](x^2 + 
       y^2)), {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {y, -\[Infinity], \
\[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> a > 0]
```

(*`ConditionalExpression[(2 \[Pi])/\[Alpha]^2, Re[\[Alpha]] > 0]`*)

There is an internal parameter to the notebooks called [`$Assumption`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions.html).
There is the documentation page for [`Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html) for the built-ins `Simplify`, `Refine` and `Integrate`.

And there is [`Assuming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html). `Assuming` is the mightiest of them but seldom in need. As my solution shows the internal option is well suited with the default settings of `$Assumption` for solving this appropriate.

By default Mathematica assumes that parameters as `Complexes`.

So the output does take Your assumption in the form of the constrain in the ConditionalExpression: α > 0 -> Re[α] > 0

Mightier is than

```
Assuming[\[Alpha] > 0 && Element[\[Alpha], Reals], 
  Normalize[E^(-\[Alpha] \[Sqrt](x^2 + y^2)), 
   Integrate[#, {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {y, -\[Infinity], \
\[Infinity]}] &]];
```

If the intention is to maintain the ConditionalExpression the Normalize has to go outmost and the internal Assumptions have to be used.

```
Normalize[E^(-\[Alpha] \[Sqrt](x^2 + y^2)), 
 Integrate[#, {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {y, -\[Infinity], \
\[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> \[Alpha] > 0] &]
```

(*    ConditionalExpression[(E^(-Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] [Alpha]) [Alpha]^2)/(
2 [Pi]), Re[[Alpha]] > 0] *)

```
Normalize[E^(-\[Alpha] \[Sqrt](x^2 + y^2)), 
 Integrate[#, {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {y, -\[Infinity], \
\[Infinity]}] &]
```

(* ConditionalExpression[(E^(-Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] [Alpha]) [Alpha]^2)/(
2 [Pi]), Re[[Alpha]] > 0]  *)

Excuse. The concept is either the assumption is given or computized by internals. Now flaw, no error, nothing forgotten.

```
Normalize[E^(-\[Alpha] \[Sqrt](x^2 + y^2)), 
 Integrate[#, {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {y, -\[Infinity], \
\[Infinity]}, 
  Assumptions -> (\[Alpha] > 0 && Element[\[Alpha], Reals]) &]]

E^(-Sqrt[x^2 + 
   y^2] \[Alpha])/(Assumptions -> \[Alpha] > 
      0 && (\[Alpha] \[Element] Reals) & (\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(-\[Infinity]\), \
\(\[Infinity]\)]\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(-\[Infinity]\), \
\(\[Infinity]\)]1 \[DifferentialD]y \[DifferentialD]x\)\)) \
#1)[E^(-Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] \[Alpha])]
```

[image]

Which is not nicely evaluable. With `Rules` this works.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination...it is not too clear right now, but I will get it in some time. There is a mistake in you first and last code because in assumptions you use a in place of  $\alpha$